# Is this apushout diagram

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, modules

Let $A, B, C, E$ and $F$ be some objects in an abeleian category $\mathcal{C}$. Let we have a commutative diagram

\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \xrightarrow{} & A & \xrightarrow{f} & B & \xrightarrow{q} & C & \xrightarrow{} & 0 \newline
&  & \downarrow &  & \downarrow &  & \downarrow &  & \newline
0 & \xrightarrow[]{} & A & \xrightarrow[g]{} & E & \xrightarrow[r]{} & F & \xrightarrow[]{} & 0
\end{array}

where the first downarrow ids an isomorphism and the second is a monomorphism.
Then 
1- Is it true to say the the third downarrow (i.e. $C\to F$) is a monomorphism?
2- Is it true to say that the right square is a pushout diagram?

Comment: Reading your title made me wonder why Apu is shouting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean the rows to be short exact sequences, as well. Then

1- Yes, by the Snake lemma.

2- Yes. The square is a pushout if and only if the square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B @>(q,-i)>> C \oplus E \\
@VVV @VVj+rV \\
0 @>>> F
\end{CD}
$$
is a pushout, where $i\!: B \hookrightarrow E$ and $j\!: C \hookrightarrow F$ are the maps from the diagram. This in turn is equivalent to the sequence $B \xrightarrow{(q,-i)} C \oplus E \xrightarrow{j+r} F \to 0$ being exact, which is routine to check.

In this situation, the squares are actually also pullbacks, and the sequence above is exact on the left, as well (since $i$ is a monomorphism).